# How to stream data in Apache Drill-Node JS?

Tags: node.js, apache-drill

I am using Apache Drill to query the data from different data sources,
I wanted to stream the data if the data is very large, but I am getting the response body as JSON object. How can I do it in Apache Drill. This is the code:

```
function executeQuery(req, res) {
  log.info("entering executeQuery");
  //var key = req.query.key;
  if (!_.isEmpty(req.body)) {
    var queryString = req.body.query;
    log.info("queryString: : " + queryString);
  }
  var query = {
    'queryType': 'SQL',
    'query': queryString
  };

  var url = 'http://localhost:8047/query.json';
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: query,
    json: true,
    url: url
  };

  var callback = function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error posting json: ', err)
      throw err;
    }
    log.info(typeof body);
    body.pipe(res);
  }
  request(options, callback);
}
```

Comment: Did you find answer for this question ? @user3649361

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Drill's Rest API to do queries. Currently the Rest API does not support the pagination of results. If you want to talk directly to Drill you can use the Drill JDBC driver. The JDBC driver also supports pagination so you do not have to handle a big blob of data at once. I have not personally tested this but I suspect you could use a NodeJS jdbc library such as [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) and point it to the Drill JDBC driver. More information about the Drill JDBC driver is [here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/)